# php5.4 en ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu

tengo la impediosa necesidad de instalar php5.4, esa y no otra. y hacerlo correr en ubuntu18.04.
ya seguí varios tutoriales y links, pero siempre choco con el problema de que los repos oldstable de ondrej ya no están (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable)

Todos señalan a esta url https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5-oldstable que evidente mente hace mucho no anda.

Alguna idea? alguna ayuda de como puedo instalarlo?.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: has probado intslando el repositorio `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: `sudo apt update`

Comment: `sudo apt install php5.4`

Comment: Se que dijiste ubuntu, pero si mal no recuerdo, creo que el repo oficial de CentOS 7.x todavía tiene por default PHP 5.4. Verifiqué y si, 5.4.16 Por si acaso el OS no te importa y quieres probar por ese lado.

Comment: Gracias @IgmerRodriguez . Eso fue lo primero que intente pero ondrej mantiene los repos de la 5.6 en adelante, de hecho era los que usaba, pero los 5.4 ya no dan soporte. luego la info que encontre es lo que publico, es informacion obsoleta por lo mencionado antes.

Comment: gracias @aeportugal, fue mi segunda opcion, encontre los repo remi, instale yum y ya empezaron a liarme las cuestiones de RH y recorde por que la deje de usar hace tanto tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Al Final di con la solución y la dejo acá por si alguien, por alguna razón se topa con una versión de PHP que ya no tiene soporte.

La mejor opción que encontré y funcionó fue [phpbrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew). Luego tuve que ir resolviendo dependencias de a poco ya que por lo que se puede apreciar descarga y compila la versión solicitada.

Comment: También podrías instalar cocker y hacerte un dockerfile con una imagen de php5.4. ..